# Generate rtf document in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a rails newbie.  Could someone tell me if there is a quick and easy way to generate rtf documents for people to download using rails?
For example if I have "views/users/show.html.erb" the view normally outputs to html so I want to people to be able to download as an identical rtf document?

Comment: found this gem https://github.com/thechrisoshow/rtf

Answer (score 7):

[ruby-rtf](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-rtf) is the gem you are looking for. There are some examples of rtf generation [here](https://github.com/thechrisoshow/rtf/tree/master/examples)

Add this to initializers/mime_types.rb:

```
Mime::Type.register "text/richtext", :rtf
```

Code to give you an idea:

```
document = RTF::Document.new(RTF::Font.new(RTF::Font::ROMAN, 'Times New Roman'))
document.paragraph do |p|
   p << "This is the first sentence in the paragraph. "
   p << "This is the second sentence in the paragraph. "
   p << "And this is the third sentence in the paragraph."
end

send_file document, :type=>"text/richtext"
```

Comment: Fixed the link. Thank you @AlexGhiculescu

Answer (score 1):

ruby-rtf - is rtf parsing

this one is for rtf generating - https://github.com/clbustos/rtf

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this on Rails 4.2 and it seems to work so far. I have not tested this on the latest version of Rails but that is next. The gem has not been maintained recently so the verdict is still out on whether or not this will meet all my requirments.

First, Nazar is correct the link should be https://github.com/clbustos/rtf in order to create RTF files from a Rails controller vs parsing RTF files.

I tried the code provided in the answers but an issue exists with using send_file in this implementation. Since send_file is meant for sending a file given a path it doesn't work as shown. On the other hand send_data is used to send a data stream directly from the Rails app. So here is the code I used for creating an RTF document for download from the controller directly.

Basic Setup:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rtf'
```

Install the gem.

config/initializers/mime_types.rb

```
Mime::Type.register "text/richtext", :rtf
```

In the "lib" Directory I created a special RTF generator (Putting the code in the controller is fine to generate an RTF document for testing but the RTF generation should be in a seperate file because code to create an RTF document can get long quickly and doesn't really belong in the controller):

lib/rtf_reporting.rb

```
class RtfReporting

  require 'rtf'

  def initialize

  end

  ...

  def self.get_rtf_document(reporting)

    document = RTF::Document.new(RTF::Font.new(RTF::Font::ROMAN, 'Times New Roman'))
    document.paragraph do |p|
      p << "This is the first sentence in the paragraph. TESTING ID = #{reporting.id}"
      p << "This is the second sentence in the paragraph. "
      p << "And this is the third sentence in the paragraph."
    end
    return document.to_rtf

  end
end
```

Controller:

app/controllers/reportings_controller.rb

```
class ReportingsController < ApplicationController

  require 'rtf_reporting'

  ...

  def show

  ...

    respond_to do |format|
      format.rtf do
        send_data RtfReporting.get_rtf_document(@reporting), :type=>"text/richtext",
          :filename => "your_file_name.rtf",
          :disposition => 'attachment'
      end      
    end

  end

end
```

I hope this helps someone. The original answers in this post helped me out! In know the biggest difference between my answer and the other answers is send_file vs send_data which in its own right is a big deal but I also wanted to provide some insight on how I would organize my code given that there is no view file like there is for an HTML or PDF based solution.